# Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: php, html5, json, google-maps, geolocalização

Estou querendo verificar o estado em que meu cliente está para mostrar os estabelecimentos próximos aquela região.

Como eu faço para conseguir essas informações através do Google Maps Geolocation API?

Existe outra maneira melhor?

O site em que venho trabalhando é o PiscouAchou.com.br

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tudo, para conseguir a localização do usuário, ele deve permitir que o seu site tenha acesso a localização dele. Porém nem sempre é uma boa prática pedir a localização dele logo de cara, é necessário um "bom motivo" para tal ação. Você pode estar lendo mais sobre isso aqui: [User Location](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/).

Outro ponto importante, a API de Geolocalização da Google, tem um limite para usuários FREE, ou seja, faça um teste com seus usuários, veja se irá passar desse limite diariamente, pois se passar, você terá que ver se é viável pagar a API ou mesmo encontrar outra para suprir o site. Exemplo aqui: [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?hl=pt-br).